# Passing variable from Flow to Invoke Class

Tags: apex, community, visual-workflow

I have this flow which works fine pulling multiple contactIds from Task but when I am passing it to InvokeClass, Invokeclass only receives one id. I am not sure why?

I have attached the screenshot of flow debug showing two contacts Ids are passed to invoke class below.

[image]

Here's developer console showing that it only received the one contact.
[image]

```
    public class contactTaskInvokeClass {
     //public static boolean contactRecursion =false; // to avoid the "maximum trigger depth exceeded" error
@InvocableMethod(label='contact Task information' description='update most recent record from task to contact')

    public static void getRecentTaskInovakable(List<List<String>> contacts) {

        System.debug('print the list from invoke class' + contacts);
 //Tasks     
        List<Contact> contactsWithLastTasks = [
            SELECT Id, Most_Recent_Contact_Task_Subject__c,       
                      Name, (
                    SELECT Subject, ActivityDate, Owner.Name,Task.WhoId,
                        Type_of_Interaction__c
                    FROM Tasks
                    ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC 
                    LIMIT 1
                )
            FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :contacts[0]
        ];

        for (Contact c : contactsWithLastTasks) {
            if (!c.tasks.isEmpty()) {
                Task lastTask = c.tasks[0];
                System.debug('print Tasks' + lastTask);

                c.Most_Recent_Contact_Task_Subject__c = lastTask.Subject;
                //c.Contact_Task_Date__c = lastTask.ActivityDate;
                // may be create field and set it text "Task" to identify if it is Task or Event

                System.debug('Print contacts list one by one?'+ contactsWithLastTasks);
                System.debug('Field one?'+ c.Most_Recent_Contact_Task_Subject__c);
                System.debug('Field two?'+ c.Contact_Task_Date__c);

            }
        }
        If(!contactsWithLastTasks.isEmpty()){
        Update contactsWithLastTasks;
        }
```

Comment: why u used `List<List<String>>`, isn't List<String> ?  in your SOQL loop where condition you used only first contact `contacts[0]` why?

Comment: If I don't use contact[0] then it give me "Invalid bind expression type of List<String> for column of type Id" this error. That is the reason I used contact[0].

Comment: have u tried, change the input parameter to `list<String>` instead of `List<List<String>>` then `where  Id IN :contacts` ? if yes did you get any Error?